# Negative scaling with spritebatch in XNA vs Primitives

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

I am using both primitives and sprites in an XNA project.  I draw my primitives using this code (a summary, not verbatim from my project):

```
transmatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(v23(-pos)) * Matrix.CreateScale(scale, -scale, 1f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(v23(offset));   
basicEffect.World = transmatrix;
basicEffect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
basicEffect.Begin();
//draw primitives blah blah
basicEffect.End();
 spritebatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.None, SpriteSortMode.Immediate, SaveStateMode.None, transmatrix);
//draw sprites blah blah
spritebatch.end()
```

if I have

```
transmatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(v23(-pos)) * Matrix.CreateScale(scale, scale, 1f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(v23(offset));
```

both the primitives and the sprites draw (but y is the inverse of what I want).
if I have

```
transmatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(v23(-pos)) * Matrix.CreateScale(scale, -scale, 1f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(v23(offset));
```

The primitives draw correctly, but the sprites don't draw at all.  What am I missing?  I have tried messing around with lots of different things but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpriteBatch sets up its own "camera" using its own parameters. To scale your camera, do this:

```
basicEffect.View = Matrix.CreateScale(1.0f, -1.0, 1.0f) * Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
```

Or you could just create a different matrix for the spritebatch.

Alternatively, you could pass in your BasicEffect to SpriteBatch:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433700.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately I don't quite understand your answer.  If I use your basicEffect code it means the primitives no longer draw(as they now have an incorrect transform) and the sprites  still don't draw as I have not changed the transmatrix.  I was going to use your other method, but am using XNA 3.1 so can't pass the Basiceffect to spritebatch.  As far as I am aware, the "camera" for spritebatch was the transmatrix that I was passing to it.  I can't set the view or projection matrix for the spritebatch separately.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to point out that if you're changing your camera, you also have to change the transmatrix. Just make that -scale in the CreateScale a scale (get rid of the minus sign)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it turns it was another problem that was causing the issue.  I have put the full explanation in another answer is it is too long for the character limit here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It turns it was another problem that was causing the issue.  I have to scale all the sprites with negative y to get them to draw correctly as mentioned in a msdn community content "Something that is not obvious when using this form of the method to map SpriteBatch to a desired coordinate system is the effect of negative scaling on the results. If you scale by a single negative number in the X or Y axes (if, for instance, you want to flip the Y-axis to match your game coordinates) the polygon that the sprite gets drawn on gets flipped in the process and gets backface-culled. It is necessary to also scale the texture by a negative in the same direction to get the results you expect."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx